# How do you get variables from rows from a table into a column table? (example) (pivot table?)

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I have trouble explaining my problem in words. so thats why my table examples:

let say i want a result table like:

```
user_id |data_a |data_b
1       |hello  |world
```

and i need to extract it out of the table "dataset" in this form

```
data_id |user_id|data_type  |data_data
1       |1      |data_a     |hello
2       |1      |data_c     |xxx
3       |2      |data_a     |xxx
4       |1      |data_b     |world
```

I do somehting like

```
SELECT user_id , data_a, data_b
FROM dataset
WHERE ( data_type = data_a OR data_type = data_b )
AND user_id = 1

AND a = ( SELECT data_data WHERE data_type = data_a )
AND b = ( SELECT data_data WHERE data_type = data_b )
```

however it is not working. i know i am doing it wrong but i dont know how to do it and how it is called. I think a privot table but i am not sure
Thats why the description is so vague i hope someone understands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is basically a `PIVOT` but MySQL does not have a `PIVOT` function so you can replicate it using an aggregate function and a `CASE` statement. So your SQL will be something like this:

```
select user_id,
  max(case when data_type = 'data_a' then data_data end) data_a,
  max(case when data_type = 'data_b' then data_data end) data_b
from dataset
group by user_id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc616/1)

Result:

```
| USER_ID | DATA_A | DATA_B |
-----------------------------
|       1 |  hello |  world |
|       2 |    xxx | (null) |
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use UNION which appends two results:

```
SELECT user_id, 'data_a', data_a FROM t1 
UNION 
SELECT user_id, 'data_b', data_b FROM t1;
```

Result

```
+---------+--------+--------+
| user_id | data_a | data_a |
+---------+--------+--------+
|       1 | data_a | hello  |
|       1 | data_b | world  |
+---------+--------+--------+
```

And for ordering by user_id:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  
    (
     (select user_id, 'data_a' as data_type, data_a as data_data from t1) 
     UNION 
     (select user_id, 'data_b' as data_type, data_b as data_data from t1)
    ) as data 
ORDER by user_id;
```

which results as

```
 +---------+-----------+-----------+
 | user_id | data_type | data_data |
 +---------+-----------+-----------+
 |       1 | data_a    | hello     |
 |       1 | data_b    | world     |
 |       2 | data_a    | bye       |
 |       2 | data_b    | people    |
 +---------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Added ordering to make it exactly as requested